# Where to add method for Rails controller for processing API response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I'm using RubyGems API Wrapper to fetch gems matching a name. I submit the search query to the API, then want to filter through the response to choose the gem that matches the query precisely (the first gem is not always the best match). I've set up my controller like so:

```
class GemsController < ApplicationController

    def show
        gems = Gems.search(params[:name]) # From RubyGems Wrapper 
        @gem = exact_name_match?(gems, params[:name]) # My own method
        if @gem
            render json: { name: @gem["name"], info: @gem["info"], dependencies: @gem["dependencies"] }, status: :ok
        else
            render json: { errors: ["Gem not found"] }, status: :not_found
        end
    end
end
```

I'm trying to keep the controller as skinny as possible so I wrote a method `exact_name_match?` but I don't know where to put it. I've read about service objects, but those seems a bit too complex for this situation.

Note: I don't have databases or models as I'm just using the API.

Answer (score 0):

I find the term service object sounds like more than it is. It really is just a plain ol' Ruby object. You could create a class (in a file like `app/services/gem_finder.rb` since `app/*` is auto-loaded) to encapsulate the behavior you're looking for with something like this:

```
class GemFinder
    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
    end

    def exact_name_match
        gems.find { |gem| @name == gem['name'] }
    end

    private

    def gems
        @gems ||= Gems.search(@name)
    end
end
```

This could be used in your controller like so:

```
class GemsController < ApplicationController

    def show
        gem_finder = GemFinder.new(params[:name])
        if @gem = gem_finder.exact_name_match
            render json: { name: @gem["name"], info: @gem["info"], dependencies: @gem["dependencies"] }, status: :ok
        else
            render json: { errors: ["Gem not found"] }, status: :not_found
        end
    end
end
```

This is beneficial in that it isolates the controller from the API wrapper. If you need to use this behavior elsewhere, all of the logic for gem searching is contained in here. If there are updates to the wrapper itself, you'll only need to change the code inside this class.

Comment: Sorry I should've mentioned that I don't have a database or models. I'm strictly using RubyGems API.